# How is it possible to partial update in Solr?

Tags: solr, schema, solrj, nested-documents, solr8

according to solr documentation

> The core functionality of atomically updating a document requires that all fields in your schema must be configured as stored (stored="true") or docValues (docValues="true") except for fields which are <copyField/

all fields in the schema.xml must be stored. I create two core test_core_1 and test_core_2.

here is **test_core_1 schema**

```
  <field name="_nest_path_" type="_nest_path_" stored="true"/>
  <field name="_root_" type="string"     indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <field name="_version_" type="plong"  indexed="false" stored="false" docValues="true" useDocValuesAsStored="false" multiValued="false"/>
  <field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="sender" type="plong" docValues="true" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <field name="text" type="text_general" uninvertible="false" omitNorms="false" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false"/>
  <field name="name" type="text_general" uninvertible="true" omitNorms="false" indexed="true" stored="false" docValues="false" multiValued="false"/>  
  <field name="uniqueId" type="text_general" uninvertible="true" omitNorms="false" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <field name="type" type="string" uninvertible="true" docValues="true" indexed="true" stored="false" useDocValuesAsStored="false" multiValued="false"/>
  <field name="value" type="string" uninvertible="true" docValues="true" indexed="true" stored="false" useDocValuesAsStored="false" multiValued="false" omitNorms="false"/>
  <field name="userId" type="plong" uninvertible="true" docValues="true" indexed="true" stored="false" useDocValuesAsStored="false" multiValued="false"/>
```

and this is **test_core_2 schema**

```
<field name="_nest_path_" type="_nest_path_"/>
<field name="_root_" type="string" docValues="false" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="false" stored="false"/>
<field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="sender" type="plong" docValues="true" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="text" type="text_general" uninvertible="false" omitNorms="false" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="name" type="text_general" uninvertible="true" omitNorms="false" indexed="true" stored="false" docValues="false" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="uniqueId"  type="text_general" uninvertible="true" omitNorms="false" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="type"  type="string" uninvertible="true" docValues="true" indexed="true" stored="false" useDocValuesAsStored="false" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="value" type="string" uninvertible="true" docValues="true" indexed="true" stored="false" useDocValuesAsStored="false" multiValued="false" omitNorms="false"/>
<field name="userId" type="plong" uninvertible="true" docValues="true" indexed="true" stored="false" useDocValuesAsStored="false" multiValued="false"/>
```

I can update just the name field in the first core (test_core_1) but for the second core, I got an error.

as we can see I have non-stored and non-docValues field like **name** in the schema in both core and the differences are related to *nest_path*, *version*, and *root*.
so how is it possible I can update the name (I mean Updating Parts of Documents Or Atomic update) in the first core but I got this error from the second core.

> Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr: This schema does not
> support partial updates to nested docs. See ref guide.

according to documentation, I must get error from both of them, I am confused about this subject in solr.
can anybody explain it?

this is my code

```
SolrInputDocument document = new SolrInputDocument();
        document.setField("id", String.valueOf(id));
        document.setField("sender", id * 2);
        document.setField("text", "sampleText" + id);
        document.setField("name", "saba" + "safavi" + id);
        document.setField("uniqueId", "test" + id + DateUtil.getNowDate().getTime());
        List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, Object> obj;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            obj = new HashMap<>();
            obj.put("type", "type" + i);
            obj.put("value", "value" + i);
            obj.put("userId", i);
            list.add(obj);
        }
        List<SolrInputDocument> metadataDocumentList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap : list) {
            SolrInputDocument metadataDoc = new SolrInputDocument();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> stringObjectEntry : stringObjectMap.entrySet()) {
                metadataDoc.addField(stringObjectEntry.getKey(), stringObjectEntry.getValue());
            }
            metadataDocumentList.add(metadataDoc);
        }
        document.addField("meta", metadataDocumentList);
        try {
            UpdateResponse response = solrClient.add("test_core_2", document);
//            UpdateResponse response = solrClient.add("test_core_1", document);
            solrClient.commit("test_core_2");
//            solrClient.commit("test_core_1");
        } catch (SolrServerException | IOException e) {
            logger.error("error occured in add or update document solr.", e);
        }

SolrInputDocument solrDocument = new SolrInputDocument();
        solrDocument.addField("id", "20");
        Map<String, Object> fieldModifier = new HashMap<>();
        fieldModifier.put("set", "sabaNew20");
        solrDocument.addField("name", fieldModifier);
        try {
            UpdateResponse response = solrClient.add("test_core_1", solrDocument);
            solrClient.commit("test_core_1");
        } catch (SolrServerException | IOException e) {
            logger.error("error occurred in delete message #",e);
        }
```

Comment: Did you at any time change the schema for the first core _after_ indexing content into it? The error isn't caused by the `name` field, it's related to documents having child documents: `// Safety check: don't allow an update to an existing doc that has children, unless we actually support this.`

Comment: The code path that gives the error has been removed in Solr 8.8, so upgrading might fix your issues. However, be aware that the note in the reference guide _isnt about the field itself_. If you submit content for that field, everything will be fine. However, if you only submit content for one of the other fields, Solr will have no way of getting the _actual value_ back for the `name` field and the field will be lost.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-14923?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=17252647#comment-17252647

Comment: @MatsLindh No, I did not change the schema file, and actually, I indexed the same documents in both cores, and all my docs have nested documents